# What does Poincare's Lemma tell me about the existence of a vector potential and what restrictions have to be considered for the domain?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields, divergence-operator, curl

I am studying Vector Calculus and Poincare's lemma was mentioned in the class notes.

Poincaré Lemma: If $U \subset \Bbb{R}^n$ is an open star-shaped set, then for every $k=\{0,...,n\}$ every CLOSED k-form in $U$ is EXACT.

I want to know if I understand the concept or the significance of the result applied to vector fields: basically, if we have a vector field defined in a *star-shaped* domain and its divergence is zero, then the vector field has a vector potential?
Now to my second question. I've seen some people use contractible domain in the definition instead of star-shaped. I know that a star-shaped domain is a contractible domain but a contractible domain isn't necessarily a star-shaped domain. Is it necessary for that the domain is star-shaped or it holds if the domain is just contractible? (a lot of sources I have read/asked always mention that the domain needs to be able to be continuously contracted to a point).

Comment: What is the exact statement of the lemma of Poincaré you are referring to? Please edit your question to include it, to improve clarity. In any case, I am pretty much sure that the “star-shaped” assumption is not an essential one and it can be weakened substantially.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I corrected it. So this does work on contractible domains that are not star-shaped? And, returning to my previous question: this result implies that all solenoidal fields that are defined in a region which is star-shaped (or just contractible) have a vector potential?

Comment: I think there is something wrong in your statement. I don’t know about 2-forms and above, but 1-forms need to be closed in order to be exact. A non-closed 1-form is not exact, regardless of the geometry of its domain.

Comment: Yes, I missed "closed" forms. I am sorry...

Comment: A star-shaped domain is contractible if I'm not wrong, but I want to know if star-shaped is really necessary. A lot of people use contractible though so I don't know what to make of this.

Comment: Contractible is enough. The proof in the star-shaped case is slightly easier, that’s why sometimes they give the statement in this way. But the result is true in greater generality.

Comment: You may have more luck getting concrete answers if you add the tag "algebraic topology."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many texts assume a star-shaped domain so that one can write down an explicit integral along rays from the "star point" to give a primitive of the closed form. But all one needs is a contractible set in order for the Poincaré lemma to be valid, and there is, in fact, a general formula obtained by integrating over the fibers of the null-homotopy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you recommend me a book where this lemma is given particular attention and detail? Most of the vector analysis books I have read don't mention it.

Comment: No, you won't find this in vector analysis. It is in books on differentiable manifolds and differential forms. You can find it in Spivak's Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry, volume 1, in Guillemin and Pollack's Differential Topology (exercises pp.180 ff), Godbillon's Elements of Algebraic Topology (chapter 11), and zillions of other books, but none too elementary. Also Munkres's Analysis on Manifolds (but I don't have it to check for a specific place).